# ASP.net DropDownList with no selected item

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-3.5

I have a ASP DropDownList with items added to it. All what I want is to make the selection after the page loaded empty so there is no a selected item.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add an empty item to the top of your dropdownlist programmatically like this:

```
myDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
myDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I understand your question but try this:

```
DropDownList1.ClearSelection()
```

or

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `SelectedIndex` property to -1 or you can add an empty entry as the first item in the data source and validate the selection on form submission.

Comment: "You can set the SelectedIndex property to -1"

this one did not work I set SelectedIndex property to -1 in loadpage event but did not work and it was working if set it to 2 or 3 but not -1.

Answer (score 1):

If the dropdownlist is being populated by DataSource, is important do the DataBind before the insert. Otherwise the item insertion does not happen.

```
myDropDown.DataBind();
myDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
myDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224636/1467453

Answer (score 1):

This should work on the client side:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="YourID" runat="server" DataSourceID="YourDataSource
DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

`yourDropDownList.Items.Clear()`

To repopulate, you can either add items statically as per womps suggestion (substituting params in the `insert()` method, or you can populate it dynamically from a data source. The backing store for list items is the [ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx).

Comment: This will remove all items, not just clear the selected item.

Comment: i agree, the question is ambiguous though

Comment: Agree on the ambiguity - I was just helping to clear up what it would do.  Not sure why you were downvoted - sorry if my comment cause that :(

Comment: this one will clear the item list and in this case I need another method to load the list again.